# Solr Velocity displays Error 400 on filter queries

Tags: solr, velocity

While using Velocity Solr I encounered an Error 400. It only occurs when I have three or more filter querys.
I noticed that the query passed in the url was:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/browse?&fq=cat%3A%22electronics%22fq=manu_exact%3A%22Samsung+Electronics+Co.+Ltd.%22&debugQuery=true&q=&fq=-author_s:[*+TO+*]
```

However when changed to

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/browse?&fq=cat%3A%22electronics%22&fq=manu_exact%3A%22Samsung+Electronics+Co.+Ltd.%22&debugQuery=true&q=&fq=-author_s:[*+TO+*]
```

(The & after electronics%22)

It works perfectly, the same occurs regard less of what Core I create. Is there any fix for this??

Comment: are both URL's created by velocity?

Comment: THe first one is generate by velocity and returns the error. However if i just add the & symbol in the url it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I found that in VM_global_library.vm
By altering

```
#macro(fqs $p)#foreach($fq in $p)#if($velocityCount && $velocityCount>1)&&#{end}fq=$esc.url($fq)#end#end
```

to

```
#macro(fqs $p)#foreach($fq in $p)#if($velocityCount && $velocityCount>1)&&#{end}fq=$esc.url($fq)&#end#end
```

(added the & at the end, for queries with less than three parameters it will render some queries with && in the url however this is not a problem.